# Android months of Year

Tags: java, android

How can i get all days of particular month and particular year..

Comment: You might want to give a little more context to your question, perhaps including code, as the current form of your question could be answered by "use a wall calendar".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit:

It is 2024 and the prior answer is not the best. As Basil pointed out JDK has newer better version of date/time utilities and you can achieve using this like follow

```
LocalDate.of(2024 , Month.JANUARY , 1)
  .datesUntil(LocalDate.of(2024, Month.FEBRUARY, 1))
  .forEach(System.out::println)
```

---

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,someMonth);//month starts from 0
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,someYear);
int noOfDayInMonthyear = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); //either 28,29,30,31
```

and iterate from 1 to `noOfDayInMonthyear`

- [Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum(int))

Comment: I want all days eg.1,2,3...31 not the count

Comment: `and iterate from 1 to noOfDayInMonthyear`

Comment: Hi @Basil, thanks for finding this stale answer. made updates.